# SQL Server database design for evaluations

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm designing this employee evaluation web page, and was wondering if my current database design is the correct one or if it could be improved.

This is my current design

Table **Agenda**:

```
+--------------+----------+----------+-----------+------+-------+-------+
| idEvaluation | Location | Employee | #Employee | Date | Date1 | Date2 |
+--------------+----------+----------+-----------+------+-------+-------+
```

`Date` is the date scheduled for the evaluation to be performed.

Date 1 and Date 2 its a period of time to retrieve some metrics from another database.

Table **Evaluations**:

```
+--------------+---------+------------+------+----------+
| idEvaluation | Manager | Department | Date | Comments |
+--------------+---------+------------+------+----------+
```

Table **Scores**:

```
+--------------+----------+-------+
| idEvaluation | idFactor | Score |
+--------------+----------+-------+
```

`idFactor` relates to another table which contains the factor and a description of it, like I said its this a correct design??

My concern its this, currently there are 60 employees, 11 managers and 12 factors, each employee its evaluated twice a year by every manager, so in the `Agenda Table` there's not much trouble since its only one record per evaluation (**60 employees = 60 records**), how ever on the `Evaluations Table` there are 11 records for every evaluation, so it goes to 660 records (**60 employees * 11 managers = 660**), and then on the `Scores Table` it goes even bigger since there are 12 factors for every evaluation, it goes to 7920 records (**660 evaluations * 12 factors each = 7920**).

Is this normal?? Am I doing it wrong?? Any input its appreciated.

**EDIT**

Location, Employee, #Employee, Manager and Department are loaded automatically by the vb.net page, they are "imported" from an `Active Directory` and its checked before insertion so duplicate names, misspelled names, and this sort of thing its not an issue.

Comment: 7,920 records is just a drop in the truck-load of water that SQL server can handle, given proper management. You should take these even further though and have separate tables for Employee, Department, Location, and Manager so that you're not duplicating those names. You're basically going to have a bunch of IDs in most of these tables.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I did thought about the employee, location and departament table, but about the manager, would it really be any improve changing the name to an Id?? Given that its mostly to identify who realized the evaluation more than if its the manager of the employee.

Comment: The manager would be the ID of another Employee record, presumably. Scratch that off my original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is you dont want to repeat string literals

So if you have

```
 id Department
  1 Sales
  2 IT
  3 Admin
```

Instead of repeat `Sales` many time you only use `1` which is smaller so things also get faster.

Second if you have users

```
 id   user
  1   Jhon Alexander
  2   Maria Jhonson
```

If `Jhon` decide change his name then you will have to check all tables and change the name. Also there is the problem if two person have same name you wont know which one are you evaluating.

So go for separated table and use the ID.

Comment: I see now the repeated character avoidance, makes sense, about the second part, I just edited my question, to clarify a bit on it, I will however use another table for them.

Comment: Is the same, as I say things change, department change name, ppl move from departments. Is just best practice. You need learn normalize db. But if your question is about size, as Cory said 8000 is nothing, Im inserting 1 million daily and just a normal person, nothing like amazon.

Comment: I do get the changing thing issue, however in my case, a department change, for example, its updated (at least its supposed to be) by the IT department on the active directory, then all future records will be inserted with the new department or attribute that changed, and previous records should remain the same, at least that's how I was asked to do it. But thanks for the advice, definitely will look more into Normalizing db. thanks!